# Proper way to manipulate date string with wrong year, but correct time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

I'm having to hit an API I have no access to fixing and I need to start a timer showing how long someone has been in a queue for.  The date I get back is in this format `1556214336.316`.  The problem is the year always shows up as 1970, but the time is the correct start time.  I need to calculate the difference between the time now, and the time the conversation was created at.  I have tried this with little success and was wondering if there is an elegant way to only get the difference in time and not the total amount of seconds.

```
 convertDateToTimerFormat = (time) => {
    const now = new Date();
    const diff = Math.round((now - parseInt(time.toString().replace('.', ''))) / 1000);
    const hours = new Date(diff).getHours();
    const minutes = new Date(diff).getMinutes();
    const seconds = new Date(diff).getSeconds();
    return `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}
```

The weird `parseInt(time.toString().replace('.', '')))` seems to fix the 1970 issue, but I still can't get the data to be manipulated how I need.

I tried the momentjs library, but their diff method only appears to allow for days and hours.

Any help/guidance, would be much appreciated.

Edit with working code:

```
  convertDateToTimerFormat = (time) => {
    const now = new Date();
    // eslint-disable-next-line radix
    const diff = new Date(Number(now - parseInt(time.toString().replace(/\./g, ''))));
    const hours = diff.getHours();
    const minutes = diff.getMinutes();
    const seconds = diff.getSeconds();
    return `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
  }
```

Comment: why is your radix zero? (you don't even need to parse numeric strings, except when using addition)

Comment: That's a good question.  I guess I assumed 0 was the default value?  My linter was yelling at me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Unix time](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) values are the number of *seconds* since the Epoch and won't have a decimal like your `1556214336.316`
If I take `1556214336` (without the `.316`) and put it in [a converter](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php) I get the output `04/25/2019 @ 5:45pm (UTC)` which is *not* 1970 — it seems an accurate time (I haven't independently verified)
It seems, then, your `1556214336.316` is the *seconds.**milliseconds*** since the epoch.

Javascript uses the same epoch, but is the number of ***milliseconds*** since the epoch, not seconds, so if I'm correct about the time you're getting you should be able to just remove the decimal place and use the resulting number string. Indeed

```
var d = new Date(1556214336316);
console.log('Date is: ' + d.toUTCString());
```

produces

```
Date is: Thu, 25 Apr 2019 17:45:36 GMT
```

which exactly matches the converter's time of "5:45pm"

```js
var d = new Date(1556214336316);
console.log('Date is: ' + d.toUTCString());
```

Assuming your value `1556214336.316` is a String coming back from a web API, you can remove the decimal and your conversion can be done like this (note you don't have to keep creating new `Date` objects):

```js
convertDateToTimerFormat = (time) => {
    const d = new Date( Number(time.replace(/\./g, '')) );
    return `${d.getHours()}:${d.getMinutes()}:${d.getSeconds()}`;
};

console.log( 'time: ' + convertDateToTimerFormat('1556214336.316') );
```

Depending on your use, you may want to use `getUTCHours()` etc. instead.

Comment: That's great.  I am also taking the current time and subtracting the oddly formatted date from it to get a start time for how long someone has been in a queue for.  Not sure if you saw that in my code.

Comment: Worked like a dream.  Much appreciated.

Comment: For subtracting the time you're better off working with timestamps, not date components; you can have `const now = `[`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) and subtract: `const diff = now - then` (where "then" is the milliseconds derived from the text string you received, with the `.` taken out)

Comment: Great.  I had edited my post after reading your answer and it appears to be working.  Appreciate you following up.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about elegant, but this calculates and displays the expired time in `h:mm:ss` format:

```js
console.log(convertDateToTimerFormat(1556215236.316)); 

function convertDateToTimerFormat(time){

  // Converts `time` to milliseconds to make a JS Date object, then back to seconds
  const expiredSeconds = Math.floor(new Date()/1000) - Math.floor(new Date(time * 1000)/1000);

  // Calculates component values
  const hours = Math.floor(expiredSeconds / 3600), //3600 seconds in an hour
        minutes = Math.floor(expiredSeconds % 3600 / 60),
        seconds = expiredSeconds % 3600 % 60;

  // Adds initial zeroes if needed
  if (minutes < 10) { minutes = "0" + minutes; }
  if (seconds < 10) { seconds = "0" + seconds; }

  // Returns a formatted string
  return `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}
```